# ADO.NET Entity Framework 6 database-first - model customisation

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6

Since recently I've been working with Entity Framework 6 in Visual Studio 2012 express using the **database-first design**.

In my Sql server database, all of my tables are plural ( example: Ts_Companies, Ts_Branches, ... ).

When I add the ADO.NET entity model the generated entities are, as you can expect, Ts_Companies, Ts_Branches, ...

Can we change this so that in are model following classes or entities are used without changing the database table names:

Database Table ------------------ Entity class

Ts_Companies ------------------- Company

Ts_Branches --------------------- Branch

...

Because now when I have to create an object like:

Ts_Companies company = new Ts_Companies();

And I would like to be able to create an object like:

Company company = new Company();

But in the entity query it would still be like:

var db = (from ct in dbContext.Ts_Companies select ct);

Comment: if you do a downvote then give a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution in the model designer. Just changed the Name propertie of each table to a singular name, eg Ts_Companies changed to Company.

It automatically changes everything of the DbContext. Only the classes had to be changed.

Also the linq entities queries uses the plural then of the singulare entity name, for example:

```
var db = (from ct in dbContext.Companies select ct);
```